# How to use fabric js (html5-Canvas Library) custom build in ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, fabricjs, custom-build

I am working in ionic application that enable to create graphics.
I am using fabric js letest version 3.2.0 and want ot use touch gesture.

I try to clone fabric js repository into my pc and try to build custom build using following command :

```
  node build.js modules=ALL
```

So, build is successful in `dist` folder, but I don't know how to install it in ionic.

Please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After compare all file in node-module/fabric and my custom build. and I got that both are same.
So I put this answer for help.

Step :

1. install letest fabric js using cmd : npm install fabric --save
2. download custom build from fabric js site : http://fabricjs.com/build/
3. open : ionic-project-folder/node modules/fabric/
4. replace dist folder Placed inside above path with downloaded custom build (dist folder)
5. re-serve project.

If any other solution is possible (like publishing into npm and install) then Please mention.

Comment: bro you saved my day. thanks very much for helping me

Answer (score 2):

This is a link to Ionic's API for interacting with the Crashlytics kit: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/crashlytics/. This should have the instructions needed to get your Ionic app integrated with Crashlytics.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but Here my question is about fabric js (html5-canvas library). not about Crashlytics.

Comment: Ah okay, the [google-fabric] tag is for Fabric Crashlytics.

Answer (score 1):

install via `npm`

```
npm i fabric
```

more details go to

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric

Comment: I tried this, but it will install only letest version of fabric js. not custom build i.e. provide by fabric js. (I want to use touch gesture from fabric js so need  to create custom build)

Answer (score 1):

For my case, I'm using a custom build fabric js version 5.2.4 with an Ionic 6 application.

1. Uninstall fabric js if you are installed it in your project with `npm uninstall fabric`
2. Download your custom build from fabric js site : http://fabricjs.com/build/
3. Add the downloaded file to `public` directory. For example `public/libs/fabric/fabric.min.js`
4. At `App.js`

```js
useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        // You may have to replace this code with your path.
        script.src = "libs/fabric/fabric.min.js";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    }, []);
```

5. re-serve project.
6. Now `fabric` should be available from `window.fabric`

Note.

The editor also add some code to my `tsconfig.json`

```json
  "include": [
    "src",
    "public/libs" // This code
  ]
```

I do not know what it does but it works fine so I leave it.